# QSortFilterProxyModel in openPersistentEditor

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to add a filtering and a sorting method to a `tableView` and for that I need to use `QSortFilterProxyModel`. My problem is that the initial model on witch I use the `QSortFilterProxyModel` needs that all the cells of the table are already open in editor mod. After I add the `QStandardItemModel` to the `QSortFilterProxyModel` the cells are not already in editable mode.

This is working as expected:

```
QStandardItemModel *model = new QStandardItemModel(0, 5, this); //reimplemented class
QItemDelegate *mydelegate = new QItemDelegate(this); //reimplemented class

ui -> tableView -> setModel(model);
ui -> tableView -> setItemDelegate (mydelegate);

for(size_t i=0; i<m_BoardingsVector.size(); i++) //a structure from a function that adds rows dynamically
{
        model -> insertRows(model -> rowCount(),1);
        for(int j=0; j<5; ++j)
        ui -> tableView -> openPersistentEditor(model -> index(model -> rowCount() - 1, j));
}
```

The cells are displayed only if I double click on the cells. That means the `openPersistestentEditor` method of the `tableView` is not working properly.

```
QStandardItemModel *model = new QStandardItemModel(0, 5, this); //reimplemented class
QItemDelegate *mydelegate = new QItemDelegate(this); //reimplemented class

QSortFilterProxyModel * m_proxyModel = new QSortFilterProxyModel();
m_proxyModel -> setSourceModel(model);

ui -> tableView -> setModel( m_proxyModel);
ui -> tableView -> setItemDelegate (mydelegate);
ui -> tableView -> sortByColumn(0, Qt::AscendingOrder);
ui -> tableView -> setSortingEnabled(true);


for(size_t i=0; i<m_BoardingsVector.size(); i++) //a structure from a function that adds rows dynamically
{
        model -> insertRows(model -> rowCount(),1);
        for(int j=0; j<5; ++j)
        ui -> tableView -> openPersistentEditor(model -> index(model -> rowCount() - 1, j));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I just had this issue and just reading your question and code excerpt made me realize the mistake:

The view (`ui->tableView`) is set to work with one model (`m_proxyModel`), but the index for the editor comes from a different model (`model`). This probably doesn't make any sense to the view.<sup>1</sup>

Changing:

```
ui -> tableView -> openPersistentEditor(model -> index(model -> rowCount() - 1, j));
```

to:

```
ui -> tableView -> openPersistentEditor(m_proxyModel -> index(model -> rowCount() - 1, j));
```

should take care of your problem, I believe.

For me it created a different problem with the editor not displaying in the right cell, but it's probably something wrong with my subclass implementation of `QAbstractProxyModel` (which is generally not recommended).

*<sup>1</sup> I took a short glimpse at the [source code](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/itemviews/qabstractitemview.cpp.html#3142)  for `QAbstractItemView`, and I didn't find an explicit restriction yet, but that's still the most reasonable explanation I can think of.*